# using && and || together (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping to get an explanation on this...

Okay say I have an if statement like this..

```
if(
  height === 0 ||
  weight === 0 &&
  waist === 0 ||
  shoeSize === 0 
) {
    ...do something 
}
```

now `height = 1`, `weight = 1` but waist and shoe size both equal `0`

will the if statment return true or false?

I currently am In a similar situation where I have an if statement if this

```
if(something){
  function 1
} else if(example given above) {
  function 2
} else {
  function 3
}
```

now I'm expecting to run `function 3` because my first if statement is `false` and then because `height && weight = 1` and not `0` the `else if` should be `false` thus going onto the else and running `function 3` but I cant seem to get past `function 2` am I implementing the `||` and `&&` correctly in this case?

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&&` operator comes first in the [order of operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) before the `||` operator.  Thus, your logic is being executed like this:

```
height === 0 || (weight === 0 && waist === 0) || shoeSize === 0
```

It seems like you want to group `height` and `weight` as a pair and `waist` and `shoeSize` as a pair-- so I'd recommend using parens to do just that:

```
(height === 0 || weight === 0) && (waist === 0 || shoeSize === 0)
```

The above will evaluate to `false` when `height` and `weight` both equal `1` but `waist` and `shoeSize` both equal `0`.

Answer (score 1):

your example will return true if `height = 1, weight = 1`
because 'AND' has higher precedence

so your example is equal
`height === 0 || (weight === 0 && waist === 0) || shoeSize === 0`

when given `height=1, weight=1`, which is equal `1===0 || (1===0 && 0===0) ||0===0`

=> `false || true || false`, thus the answer is true

Answer (score 1):

Your first statement is `true` because your last `OR-Condition` seems to be `true`

```
false || false && false || true  // ==> true
```

You can have any condition which results in `true` without braces that ends with `|| true` ... for example:

```
false || false && false || false || false && false || true // ==> true
```

You may have to add braces to get your correct condition ... something like:

```
(height === 0 || weight === 0) && (waist === 0 || shoeSize === 0)
```